# SQL Server Availability Group Issue - Removed from primary and secondary stucking in resolving

Tags: sql

I have an availability group that was removed on the primary server.  The secondary server has this availability in a resolving state.

When I try to drop the availability group I get cannot drop the availability group 'Name', because it does not exist or you do not have permission (I am an admin).

I try to remove the database by issuing:

```
ALTER DATABASE [DATABASE NAME] SET HADR OFF
```

And I get:

> The availability group 'group guid' and/or its local availability replica does not exist.  Verify that the specified availability group name is correct, and that the local availability replica has joined the availability group, then retry the operation.

Anyone know how to permanently remove this availability group?  Cannot do anything with the 2 databases that are in it.

Answer (score 1):

Restart of the SQL Service solves the issue. The deleted availability group goes away on the secondary service once complete